# Collision detection leading to color detection?

Tags: swift, collision-detection, collision, skspritenode, color-detection

How can I check if, when I collide with an SKSpriteNode in the middle of two rectangles with a ball, the ball and the two rectangles are the same color?

For example, if my two rectangles are red, and my ball is blue, I want it to detect that the colors of my rectangle and the ball are different. If they are the same color, then I don't want anything to happen. If they aren't, I'll write the code that makes the player lose. But how can I detect the color difference when the ball collides the skspritenode located in the middle and in between the two rectangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that your change your "pair" of walls to become a trio of walls instead. This third wall should have a different categoryBitMask. (`PhysicsCategory.wallSpace` seems to fit with your current naming scheme.)

This "wallSpace" needs to be positioned *between* the two existing walls. It should be given the *same* color as its siblings through your color-change logic, but here comes the trick: set it's alpha to 0.

This way you can check for collisions between this invisible wall and your ball and perform actions based on the color-information.

Comment: This is like having a book in my hand, except I can't read. If you want to help me, you're going to have to take me through all of that step by step. Sorry for causing such a hassle.

Comment: Stack isn't really the arena for full blown tutorials. I'm not sure how to explain this so that you can understand: You put a sprite between the two colored walls and check when the ball contacts this (new) sprite.

Comment: Wait, so you want my Sprite to be the same color as the walls it's in between, using the same color randomization code as I do on my ball, and then check if the ball and Sprite are the same color?

Comment: Yes that was always the general idea, was it not? In my above answer I also suggest adding a third wall WITH THE SAME COLORADO but with its alpha set to 0. This to make it easier to decide when the ball passes between the _visible_ walls.

Comment: Because I'm lazy, here's what I did. I duplicated the node that detected if my ball hit the wall. But I change the categorybitmask so it won't collide with my ball. It's like this: if (color detection I can't figure out but if wall is same color as ball) then use categorybitmask that doesn't collide with anything. Else set the categorybitmask to wall. So it treats a collision of different colors the exact same as it would a wall. Which is fine. If only I knew how to construct an if statement that could accurately identify both the color of the wall and the ball as its changing in the game.

Comment: You really got me baffled now. The _exact_ checks required to compare the colors are found in my own answer to your question in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873958/comparing-two-sprites-colors-based-on-random-colorization and _also_ in appzYourLife's answer (to another version of your question) in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871177/do-an-skaction-if-the-colors-of-two-sprites-arent-the-same You have all the pieces. Now try putting them together...

Comment: No one has told me how to check if my ball and wall are the same color. appzYourLife just told me to set initial color values to my wall and my ball. And then do an if statement. How does that help me? That statement is always true. Of course Wall1.color == Ball.color when you set them both to red right before that. That's  all I need though. Please look at my colorize code, because I think that's where the problem is. Maybe there's another way do it. Maybe I could say: if the random color picked for wall 1 is red, and the random color picked for my ball is red, then whatever. I don't know.

Comment: Yes, someone did. That someone being me. The code I supplied was based on the contact-checking code you already have and _explicitly_ checks the that the color between the two contacting nodes are the same inside the logic that has already established that the contact IS between the ball and one of the walls... (I'll still have a look at your color-logic, but _you_ really need to work on trying to _understand_ the answers we supply, not just incorporate the code examples blindly... )