# Comparing two sprites colors based on random colorization?

Tags: swift, if-statement, collision-detection, uicolor, color-detection

This code colorizes my ball.

```
var colorize1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)

        var colorize2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)

        var colorize3 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)

        var actions = [colorize1, colorize2, colorize3]

        var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

        var action = actions[randomIndex]

        let seconds = 0.14
        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


            self.Ball.runAction(action)


        })

    }
```

This code colorizes my walls.

```
var colorBucket = [UIColor]()

func randomColor() -> UIColor {

    if colorBucket.isEmpty {
        fillBucket()
    }

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorBucket.count)))
    let randomColor = colorBucket[randomIndex]
    colorBucket.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
    return randomColor

}

func fillBucket() {
    colorBucket = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor()]
}
```

I need to write an if statement that detects whether or not the ball and wall are the same color when I collide with an spritekitnode() located in between my walls.

I've tried these:

```
if Wall1.color == UIColor.redColor() && Wall2.color == UIColor.redColor() && Ball.color != UIColor.redColor {

died = true

}
```

My main issue is writing the if statement that determines if the ball and walls are the same color. I have the collision part down. 
Thank you so much for your help.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB




    let ballWasContacted = firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Ball || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Ball
    var wallWasContacted = firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Wall || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Wall
    let scoreWasContacted = firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Score || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Score
    let colorWasContacted = firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Color || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Ball

    if ballWasContacted {
        if scoreWasContacted {
            score += 1
            scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
            let scoreNode = firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCat.Score ? firstBody.node : secondBody.node
            scoreNode!.removeFromParent()
        } else if wallWasContacted {
            enumerateChildNodesWithName("wallPair", usingBlock: ({
                (node, error) in
                node.speed = 0
                self.removeAllActions()

                                }))


            if died == false {
                died = true
                createBTN()
                fallDie()
            }
        }
    }

    else if colorWasContacted {


    }

}
```

The colorWasContacted isn't really being used right now, but everything else is.

Code to change color of wall.

```
action = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(randomColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)
```

Wall1.runAction(action)

This is what happened when I added the breakpoints.

[Breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8jcg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts only happen with two elements at a time, so you could do something like this in your `didBeginContact` (edit, based on your actual code):

```
...
else if wallWasContacted {
    let sprite1 = firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let sprite2 = secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode
    if sprite1.color.isEqual(sprite2.color) {
        // Whatever your heart desires...
    } else {
       // Something else you'd like to have done...
    }

    enumerateChildNodesWithName("wallPair", usingBlock: ({
        (node, error) in
        node.speed = 0
        self.removeAllActions()
    }))

    if died == false {
        died = true
        createBTN()
        fallDie()
    }
}
```

As this might help with this isolated issue, I belive (from looking through your other threads) that you need to rethink the whole logic when it comes to discovering passing *between* walls...

Comment: I got this error. "Value of type 'SKNode?' has no member 'color'"

Comment: Yeah, but you really need to start not expecting every answer to be a 100% finished thing you can just copy and paste... In this case you need to cast the nodes to SKSpriteNodes first. But for all I know, you _could_ have a subclass that you need to access some special function nobody at S.O. knows about...

Comment: I appreciate your help. I know it can be aggravating to deal with a beginner like me. What do I need to do? I have scoreNode that increases my score when my ball collides with it. I don't have a subclass. I have walls that colorize, and a ball that colorizes, and collision properties for the walls when my ball hits it.

Comment: Don't worry about being a beginner. We've all been there. Please don't abandon your own questions though when people reply. Could you please show me your didBeginContact as I believe there might be something to hook up to there that would make a lot of sense before I change the above...

Comment: Is the only way to detect if my the color of my ball and the color of two walls are the same is to have a collision while the ball is in between, and then when I collide, ask if the ball and walls are the same color, if they are, then somehow ignore the collision, but if they differ, collide?

Comment: Well collisions are not something _you_ trigger its triggered by the physicsBody.categories. But the general idea is to handle logic based on the nodes that come into contact with each other.

Comment: What's wrong with saying this? if Wall1.color.isEqual(Ball.color) && Wall2.color.isEqual(Ball.color) {         do nothing  } else {    die       }

Comment: Well, first of all the statements on each side of the && is performing the exact same check twice. Secondly: WHEN and WHERE are you planning to check this?

Comment: I want to check that when I collide with a flat line that goes across the entire screen and is located at the bottom of each wall. That's the logic I'm trying to accomplish. If the colors are equal when I collide, nothing should happen. But if they're different, I should lose.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. Well, if you're keeping a reference to the walls and the ball, then yes you could could compare the color of these the moment the ball contacts the line. But this is also the third or fourth slightly different explanation of what you are trying to achieve I've read so far, and that makes it _really_ hard to help you.

Comment: It's changing so much because I don't know the best and most logical way to code this. I don't know if I even need a collision to detect if my ball and the walls it goes between are the same color once it enters the gap. I need you to tell me that part. On one of my threads I posted a picture of my game if you need an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't care how its done. Since I don't know, I'm counting on you to decide how to do it. Here's a scenario: My ball is red, and I attempt to go through a gap made by two blue walls. As soon as my ball enters that gap, I should lose.

Comment: And that's the version your sticking with? ;-) As I've outlined in one of your other questions I'd stick an invisible sprite between the two walls following the same color-change logic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849475/collision-detection-leading-to-color-detection/37888303#37888303

Comment: Literally all I need is the if statement. Forget about all the collision stuff. I don't know when things got so out of hand. I JUST need an if statement. But the problem is that if I print(Ball.color), or Wall1.color, it thinks they are always the same value. So If I say if Wall1.color.isEqual(Ball.color), it always returns true. The issue is that swift or something can't figure out the color value of my walls OR my ball. If it could do that, my app would be finished practically. If you have any knowledge to give me on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: OK, that's seems fine. Now: Please incorporate the if logic I've described. Then ad a breakpoint in the places where I've commented `//Whatever your heart desires` and `// Something else you'd like to have done.` Then trigger the collision for each case and check that it arrives at the breakpoint you expect.

Comment: What exactly are Sprite1 and Sprite2? Are those supposed to be my walls?

Comment: The answer is NO. _One_ of them is a wall. Read the code you've incorporated. You _need_ to understand the code if you're to learn anything.

Comment: Oh I see. This code will work when I add a third wall in between my two original walls?

Comment: No, this particular bit of code will not work but we'll use similar logic when (if) we ever get there. Here is what the current code does. It sets a Bool true if one of the specified types are among the two contactBodies. If one of those was the ball it goes into the `if ballWasContacted` part of the code. If a wall was also contacted (in other words it was the _other_ sprite it will enter the `else if wallWasContacted` part. The two sprites are then 1 wall sprite _and_ your ballSprite and you can compare the colors. Get this to work then we can revisit the invisible wall...

Comment: Come on, there is such a thing as Googling or using the search-field in the top-right corner of this site... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931959/how-do-you-add-a-breakpoint-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

As you are mixing questions and re-asking them (worded slightly differently) I'll attempt dealing with your colorization problems here as well, as this is most likely where you are failing. I say *most likely* because the code you supply does not show us that you colorize the walls *at all*.

It shows us that:

1. You have logic in place to change color on the ball.
2. You have logic to pick out a random color from a colorBucket.
3. You have logic to refill the bucket when all the colors have been
   used.

It does *not* show us that you actually change the color-information for the walls. Could you please supply this part of the code (if it exists).

Comment: There's an issue that you might be able to explain. I don't want a solution to the problem, just an explanation. So when I write the print(Wall5.color) I receive this: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 0. But the colors of walls are changing. Yet each time a new set of walls spawn it repeats that print statement. But if I say Wall5.color = UIColor.redColor() it's obviously going to continuously print UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1. I guess I need to somehow store the color that it picks from the randomColor() each time its called.

Comment: No, the idea is that you hook into what's already available to you. The SpriteNodes have a property `color`. When you _change_ the color the property is also changed. Have you tried setting those breakpoints to see that you get the expected behavior?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of what happened when I added the breakpoints. Updated it in the question section.

Comment: Is there perhaps some way we can move this discussion out of Slack (this isn't really the venue for it). Anyways: You need to learn how to debug your code: While at the breakpoint you can type the following in the right-hand panel, bellow (lldb) `po sprite1.color` and press enter then `po sprite2.color` and present enter. This should print out the color values for the two nodes at the time of contact.

Comment: My email is tippytech@gmail.com, sprite1 was red when Wall1 was red. and Sprite2 was UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 2.98023e-08 2.98023e-08 1... Which i think is the color of my ball. I think those big numbers happen when it colorizes my ball the same color twice.